# Compress image to 100 KB

Tags: java, image, file, io

I need to compress an image to 100 kB so that I can upload it to Active Directory. I wrote this code, but it does not work with all image sizes. At some iteration of the loop, it simply leaves the same image size.

```
private static byte[] compressImage(byte[] originalImage) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream originalImageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(originalImage);
    ByteArrayOutputStream compressedImageStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Thumbnails.of(originalImageStream)
            .scale(1)
            .outputQuality(COMPRESSION_QUALITY)
            .toOutputStream(compressedImageStream);

    byte[] compressedImageBytes = compressedImageStream.toByteArray();
    if (compressedImageBytes.length <= MAX_SIZE_IN_BYTES) {
        return compressedImageBytes;
    }
    return compressImage(compressedImageBytes);
}
```

I tried to write in pure Java, the same problem arose

Comment: At a certain point you can compress stuff any further, unless you reduce quality. And even then there are lower limits.

Comment: it is funny that this code even properly exits as I would expect it to never leave the loop when the image is not "compressible" anymore.